# How to calculate property in a chained linq query

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to compute 'on-the-fly' `Division` based on `Department` and `JobTitle` 
with eventually applying some Transformations such as concatenating
in the chained linq query below ?

```
  public static List<Developer> GetDevelopersData(List<Employee> employees)
    {
        List<Developer> developers = 
        employees.Where(x => x.Department == "Dev")
                 .Select(x => new Developer
                     {
                         Name = x.Name,
                         Department = x.Department,
                         JobTitle = x.Function,
                         Division = "Department" + "/" + "Function" // based on previous properties
                     }).ToList();

        return developers;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose Function and Departement are string type ?

```
    List<Developer> developers =
    employees.Where(x => x.Department == "Dev")
             .Select(x => new Developer
             {
                 Name = x.Name,
                 Department = x.Department,
                 JobTitle = x.Function,
                 Division = String.Concat(x.Function, "/", x.Department)
             }).ToList();

    return developers;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you could do:

```
Division = string.Format("{0}/{1}", x.Department, x.Function)
```

Assuming you just want the two properties concatenated into a string.

Answer (score 0):

to compute on the fly, you can use **let**

```
 (from x in employees
 let MyFunction=String.Concat(x.Function, "/", x.Department)//you can use whatever you want here
 select new Developer()
 {
       Name = x.Name,
       Department = x.Department,
       JobTitle = x.Function,
       Division = x.MyFunction
  }).ToList();
```